# Calculus world problem expansion of air

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How would I solve this problem?

The adiabatic law for expansion of air is $P(V)^{1.4}=C$ when P is pressure V is volume and C is a certain constant.At a given instant the volume is 30 cubic feet and the pressure is 60 psi. At what rate is the pressure changing if the volume is decreasing at a rate of 2 cubic feet per second?

I know that $\frac{dv}{dt}=-2$

$P(1.4)\frac{dv}{dt}+V^{1.4}\frac{dp}{dt}=0$

$60(1.4)(-2)+30^{1.4}\frac{dp}{dt}=0$

$-168+116.9417\frac{dp}{dt}$

$168=116.9417\frac{dp}{dt}$

$\frac{dp}{dt}=1.4366$ but would this be right.

Comment: typo: $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(PV^{1.4})=1.4PV^{0.4}\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}$; moreover the expressions 2, 3 and 4 don't mean anything without an equality sign..try to make at least some effort

Comment: ok I will fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help make the answer more sensible:
Given $\;PV^{1.04} = C\;$, and differentiating gives us:
$$P(1.4)V^{0.4}\frac{dv}{dt}+V^{1.4}\frac{dp}{dt} = 0$$

Now proceed as you did, but keep the equality sign as you substitute values and such: $V = 30, \;\;P = 60,\;\;\frac{dv}{dt} = -2$ to solve for $\;\dfrac{dp}{dt}$.

Comment: I see my mistake with formula thanks.

Comment: You're always welcome, Fernando!

Comment: and don't forget the units ;)

Comment: Hmm I got $\frac{dp}{dt}=5.60$ so that is the rate the pressure increases.

Comment: Nicely done Amy.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**:

$PV^{\gamma}=C \implies \dfrac{dP}{dt}\cdot V^{\gamma}+(\gamma)V^{(\gamma-1)} \cdot \dfrac{dV}{dt}\cdot P=0$